# How to unsubscribe from in a switchMap called callback function in RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following autosuggestlist construct in Angular & RxJS:

```
this.autosuggestlistSubscription = this.input.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((value: string) => {
      return this.myBackendRequestFunction(value).pipe(catchError(err => {
        this.errorFn(err);
        return EMPTY;
      }));
    })
  )
  .subscribe((suggestlist: Array<OptionItem>) => {
    // go on with the suggestlist ...
  });
```

We register ourself for changes in an input field. And everytime we type in this field, the pipe starts working. Since we want to cancel the previous request immediately after user types the next one, we use switchMap.

The Problem is, when we call the unsubscribe for our autosuggestlistSubscription (in component's destroy lifecycle):

```
this.autosuggestlistSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

the subscribe part is not called, so the autosuggest does not run anymore. But the myBackendRequestFunction is still called in switchMap (we see the requests firing in developer tools network tab). So our unsubscription works only for the subscribe part.

How can i ensure that the whole construct is unsubscribed and not called anymore?

Comment: If you unsubscribe then `switchMap` unsubscribes from the inner Observable so it should be cancelling all pending requests (depends on what `myBackendRequestFunction` does internally). You'll see the requests in dev tools but when you unsubscribe they should be marked as canceled.

Comment: they are still fired strangely.. may be it has sth. to do with the inner pipe within the switchMap?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on StackBlitz or somewhere else?

Comment: not so easy.. :/

Comment: Can you show what's inside `this.myBackendRequestFunction`?

Comment: just http.get. But we have updated our RxJS version to 6.4.0 and the problem solved! :/ Thank you though. Apparently the version 6.3.3 has this bug: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4434

Answer (score 0):

the inner subscription should get canceled if the input-value has changed. Maybe the code would be a little bit cleaner this way:

```
this.autosuggestlistSubscription = this.input.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap((value: string) => this.myBackendRequestFunction(value),
    catchError(err => {
        this.errorFn(err);
        return EMPTY;
      })
  .subscribe((suggestlist: Array<OptionItem>) => {
    // go on with the suggestlist ...
  });
```

You could even work with (without subscribe()):

```
this.autosuggestlist$ = this.input.valueChanges.pipe(... pipes from fist code block...);
```

and in your html with something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of autosuggestlist$ | async">{{item.fooPropertyName}}</li>
</ul>
```

This way you wouldn't have to unsubscribe at all.